# linking not done issue in flex

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, flex-lexer

I am trying to make an object file via "cc -c -o " but I get the following statement ,what should I do to solve this,thanks in advance

```
~/hedor1>lex -t example.l > example.c
~/hedor1>cc -c -o example.o example.l
cc: example.l: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

the first line to produce the example.c is working and I get the .c file but when I write the second line I get the above!

Comment: Compile the `.c` file, not the lex source!

Comment: If you store this code in a file count.l, you can build an executable from it by
lex -t count.l > count.c
cc -c -o count.o count.l
cc -o counter count.o -ll

Comment: it should be done like that I have did it once but after that it just showed the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the flex source to the compiler, which apparently interprets it as being a linker input file, and complains because you told the compiler not to do the linking step.

The second command should have been:

```
cc -c -o example.o example.c
```

Comment: But I did before what makes him not to do that again and show the message above?